# How to get the jwt authentication using Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, javabeans

i'm new to Spring Boot and i'm trying to do the JWT Authentication so i followed several tutorials like this one https://www.learncodewithdurgesh.com/blogs/jwt-authentication-with-spring-boot-31 but i always get this type of error

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method securityFilterChain in com.example.jwtauth.Config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.

i don't know why i keep getting this type of error in every tuto i follow can someone help me please i really need to understand it to finish my project